# toast error message showing up two times

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, toast

based on a field value as null on account I'm showing up a toast error message as below:

```
if(field == null) {
            console.log('comin inside field null')

            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                mode: 'sticky',
                type : 'error',
                message: ' field on account should not be null!',
                messageTemplate: 'The field on account should not be null. Please update it here {1}!',
                messageTemplateData: ['Salesforce', {
                    url: 'https://***--***.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/'+ accountId +'/view',
                    label: accountName,
                }]

            });
            resultsToast.fire();
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();

        }
```

This is showing two error messages like:

[image]

If I write a normal toast messgae, its showing just one error pop up, but I need to display the account link on the toast message, what is wrong in this code. Please advise.

Comment: need more code to know, looks like the method is executed twice, once with the account variable, the other without....so, its most likely your logic that is flawed.

Comment: @glls I am able to fix it now, I have put if opp != null then it will execute, the first time its taking opp and all other fields null so may be that's why. Thank you for your comment.